# MacbookPro 10.9.1 Installing linux wirless drivers

Tags: wireless, internet, macbook-pro

I've just installed Linux on my Mac 10.9.1 and I have no Internet connection or any Wi-Fi signal. I've installed Linux by creating a partition and I really need help on this. None of the tutorials I've found works on my MacBook Pro version, so if somebody could help me with this issue I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your networking devices. Open a terminal Ctrl+Alt+t and run and post: lspci -nn | grep -e 0200 -e 0280. The pipe symbol | is on the right side of my US keyboard on the same key with \.

Comment: Also, FWIW, you can purchase wireless USB cards that are 100 % compatible with linux for $10. Might be a better option then fighting with an unsupported card.

Answer (score 0):

You need to plugin Ethernet LAN cable to computer to have network first. Then open `Software & Updates`, open `Additional Drivers` tab. If nothing is wrong, the driver you need will be there, just put a check on the Broadcom wl driver